# Javascript regex: is there anyway to write a regex which gives true if backreference is NOT matched

Tags: javascript, regex

so here is my problem: I'm checking an input of 2 years with a hyphen. Like:

2001-2015

To test this, I use the simple regex

```
/^([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{4})$/
```

I know groups aren't needed, and `(19|20)[0-9]{2}`, is a closer match to the basic year exp, but bear with me.

Now, if my requirement was to match the two years only if they are the same, i could have used a backreference like:

```
/^([0-9]{4})-\1$/
```

which matches `2000-2000` but not `2000-2014`

My actual requirement is exactly the opposite. I want it to match if the years are different but not if they're same. That is, `2000-2014` should match. `2000-2000` should not.

And using the negative of the boolean I find is not an option. I need this for a huuuge regex which is supposed to match a whole lot of different date formats. This is just a part of it.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need to do this in a regex? Just match all of these "yyyy-yyyy" cases and filter them with a function.

Comment: @Sacho - thanks, but as I said, this is part of a larger requirement and I have to use regex. I simplified it to see if it conceptually possible, which I now know is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to achieve this:

```
^([0-9]{4})-(?!\1)[0-9]{4}$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eD4aU6/1)

This is almost the same pattern, except it inserts a condition check using the backreference.
`(?!\1)` will fail if `\1` matches at its position.

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative lookahead:

```
\b(\d{4})-(?!\1)\d{4}\b
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uN1pM0/1)

Answer (score 2):

Use Negative Lookahead.

Like this :

```
^([0-9]{4})-(?!\1)[0-9]{4}$
```

It does work on your example.

Explanation : **(?!\1)** Assert that it is impossible to match the regex **\1**. Then you just put your 4 digits requirement.